# macport : "Error: The 'list' command failed: The specified group 'python' does not exist." on MAC

Tags: python, macports

I'm on macOS, and I'm trying to install a package on python called "obspy" using macport.
I've already installed Xcode and macport, and tried the code below :

```sh
sudo port select python
```

Then the error message is returned :

[screen shot of my terminal while entering the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0essy.png)

Is there a way to "create" or make sure that macport rencognizes the group "python"?
(Of course, I have python, and the path of python is `/usr/bin/python`)

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: MacPorts (a) does not install python in `/usr/bin/python` and (b) it uses specific version numbers when calling `port select`. Refer to the documentation on how to use multiple versions of Python on `macOS`.

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage(`man port`):

> For a given group, selects a version to be the default by creating appropriate symbolic
>              links. For instance, python might be linked to python2.6. Available select groups are
>              installed as subdirectories of ${prefix}/etc/select/ and can be listed using --summary. To
>              list the available versions in a group, use --list. To see which version is currently
>              selected for a group, use --show. To change the selected version for a group, use --set.
>
> ```
>       For example:
>
>          port select --summary
>          port select --show python
>          port select --list python
>          port select --set python python34
> ```

You can find all existing groups by:

```
port select --summary
```

`port select` is for selecting what is macports' default python.
For example, if you prefix is `/opt/local`, then the default python is `/opt/local/bin/python` and it's just a symbolic link to a python version.

---

I suppose you are trying to select a python to work with and then install `obspy`. You don't really need to go through all that trouble as macports manages it all.

You can simply do the following steps:

```
sudo port search obspy
```

You will get something like:

```
obspy_select @1.0 (python)
    Common files for selecting default ObsPy version

py-obspy @1.1.0_1 (python, science)
    Python framework for processing seismological data

py27-obspy @1.1.0_1 (python, science)
    Python framework for processing seismological data

py35-obspy @1.1.0_1 (python, science)
    Python framework for processing seismological data

py36-obspy @1.1.0_1 (python, science)
    Python framework for processing seismological data

py37-obspy @1.1.0_1 (python, science)
    Python framework for processing seismological data

Found 6 ports.
```

Choose the port that matches your need.

For example,

```
sudo port install py-obspy
```

As python is its dependeny, macports will manage installing it.
After installing `py-obspy`, start macports' python:

(I am assuming your prefix `/opt/local`)

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

and then try importing `obspy`.

If you are unsure about your prefix, check it by:

```
echo "${"$(which port)"%/bin/port}"
```